# How to resolve Gradle sync failed error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The error message is:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
Required by:project :app
Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0-beta1/appcompat-v7-26.0.0-beta1.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0-beta1/appcompat-v7-26.0.0-beta1.pom'.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1
```

specify:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Beta-1 in Your Projects Creates Issue because beta files gets updated in very few span of time so Sync Cannot fetch from the Link, Always use Stable versions
Try Using

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

or

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`